# C program for counter?

Tags: c, counter

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int task1_counter = 0;
int task2_counter = 0;
int task3_counter = 0;


void checkTasks()
{

    if(++task1_counter ==2 )
    {
        task1_counter = 0;
        printf("etas1\n");
    }
    else if(++task2_counter == 10)
    {
        task2_counter = 0;
        printf("etas2\n");

    }
    else if(++task3_counter == 100)
    {
        task3_counter = 0;
        printf("etas3\n");
    }
    else
        printf("error\n");
}


int main()
{

    checkTasks();
    return 1;

}
```

I created a counter and it has to print the statement for counter = 2, 10 and 100 but the above code is going directly to print error. what is the problem in the above code
could someone please guide me ??

Comment: Why shouldn't it? The first time you call it your vars are all zero and can't possibly be 2, 10, or 100. Since you call the function only once you never ever get a chance to reach at least 2.

Comment: what could be the solution ??

Comment: I think you're looking for `>` instead of `==` operation.

Comment: You have to initialise variables to 1 at least so that ++i=2

Comment: What do you want to do ?

Comment: What output do you want to get ?

Comment: it should print the printf statement when the task1_counter =2, 10 and 100

Comment: @user3367968 you want it to loop over the numbers from 1 to 100? You want to print error message for every other case or just in a special case? Please clarify or give us part of the expected output so we know what you really want.

Comment: You can't just complain that something isn't doing what you want, without telling us what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Well you've set the all the variables to 0, then in the if statements you only increment them by one. Hence they're all going to equal one.

Comment: how to print the printf statement when the task1_counter =2, task2_counter = 10 and task3_counter=100 ?

Comment: @user3367968 Your function already does that, but the thing is, the `task1_counter` never becomes `2`, and the others never become the corresponding values... They start off as 0, and they become 1, then the programme ends.

Comment: What exactly is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: how to print the printf statement when the task1_counter =2, task2_counter = 10 and task3_counter=100 ?

Comment: how to print that statement when the counter is 2, 10 and 100 ??

Comment: You're current code can't work. If task1_counter did equal 2, which it doesn't, then the other else if statements wouldn't be executed.
I meant what is the purpose of the program?

Answer (score 0):

```
int x,y;
y=++x; //x is incremented by 1, y is assigned to the new value of x
```

---

```
int task1_counter = 0;
int task2_counter = 0;
int task3_counter = 0;
```

Since all are `0`, `++task1_counter`, `++task2_counter`, `++task3_counter` will be `1`. So control will go to the `else` part.

Comment: but in any case they won't arrive to 10 or 100 as I don't see any loop there.... which makes his code really strange.. difficult to know what he wants to achieve.

Comment: @Jekyll Maybe he wanted to loop over `checkTasks()` to see what's happening?

Comment: how to print the printf statement when the task1_counter =2, task2_counter = 10 and task3_counter=100 ?

Comment: I think so as well, but I am not sure he knows he needs to loop and break on the default @RikayanBandyopadhyay.

Comment: @user3367968 Do you realize that the `task_counter`s never equal `1`, so the `else` part is executed?

Comment: @user3367968 Maybe in `main()` you wanted `while (condition) { checkTasks(); }`?

Answer (score 0):

You start off with

```
int task1_counter = 0;
int task2_counter = 0;
int task3_counter = 0;
```

then you run your tests:

```
if(++task1_counter ==2 )        // increases task1_counter from 0 to 1 then evaluates to false.
else if(++task2_counter == 10)  // increases task2_counter from 0 to 1 then evaluates to false.
else if(++task3_counter == 100) // increases task3_counter from 0 to 1 then evaluates to false.
else printf("error\n");         // now you print the error message
```

I don't know what exactly you wanted to do but I guess you wanted a `for` loop somewhere, but can't really say more without further information about what you wanted to archieve.

---

You might have wanted to do add a loop like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int task1_counter = 0;
int task2_counter = 0;
int task3_counter = 0;


void checkTasks()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; ++i) {
        if(++task1_counter ==2 )
        {
            task1_counter = 0;
            printf("etas1\n");
        }
        else if(++task2_counter == 10)
        {
            task2_counter = 0;
            printf("etas2\n");

        }
        else if(++task3_counter == 100)
        {
            task3_counter = 0;
            printf("etas3\n");
        }
        else
            printf("error\n");
    }
}


int main()
{

    checkTasks();
    return 1;

}
```

which would print:

```
error
etas2
error
error
error
error
error
error
error
etas10
.
.
.
```

Comment: how to print the printf statement when the task1_counter =2, task2_counter = 10 and task3_counter=100 ?

Comment: It would print them, the problem is you just don't have any number except 0 and 1 ever in your program, I'll update with what you might have wanted in a sec.